# Exporting graphs in R

Tags: r, graph

I have two graphs that I plotted in R and I want to export it as a high-resolution picture for publication.

For example:

```
 a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
 b<-c(2,3,4,6,7,8,9)
 par(mfrow=c(2,1))
 plot (a,b)
 plot(a,b)
```

I usually export this graph by:

```
 dev.copy(jpeg,'test.jpeg',width=80,height=150,units="mm",res=200)
 dev.off()
```

However I always find this process a bit troublesome.  The graph that was plotted in R does not necessarily look like the one that I exported.    Therefore, I am wondering if there is a way to specifiy the dimensions and resolution of graphs before I plot them so that I can visually inspect the graphs before I export them?

Thank you

Comment: jpeg is usually the worst possible choice of output format for plots. png, tiff, or vector formats such as pdf, svg or eps would probably be more suitable.

Comment: For print publications I would use a resolution of 300dpi, rather than 200dpi. Also, as @baptiste says, jpeg is a poor choice. A pdf is best, or tiff if raster.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
png('out.png')

a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
b<-c(2,3,4,6,7,8,9)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot (a,b)
plot(a,b)
dev.off()
```

As [baptiste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471093/baptiste) said, jpeg is the worst format you can choose. You should take a look at the help for the `bmp` and `png` functions (with `?bmp` and `?png`). Both `bmp` and `png` have `height`, `width`, and `res` arguments that you can use to specifiy the dimensions and resolution of the output. Also, I wouldn't recommend the use of `dev.copy`. As you could see, the result of the output is not always what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Bonifacio2's answer, you if you call the function first to make the plot, you can also define your margins and window size etc before doing any actual plotting.  That way you have full control over all fig specs.

```
pdf(file='test.jpeg',width=80,height=150,units="mm")  #I prefer pdf, because they are editable files
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
b<-c(2,3,4,6,7,8,9)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot (a,b)
plot(a,b)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cowplot package to combine multiple panels in several different ways. For example, in your case, we export one plot with two panels arranged in two rows and one column. I assume that you prefer to use base-R 'plot' function instead of ggplot.

```
library(cowplot)
p1 <- ~{
  plot(a,b)
  }

p2 <- ~{
  plot(b,a)
}

png("plot.png",
    width = 3.149606, # 80 mm 
    height = 5.905512, # 150 mm 
    units = 'in',
    res = 500)

plot_grid(p1, p2, labels = "AUTO", nrow = 2, ncol = 1)

dev.off()
```

Note that you can either remove the labels if not needed or print small letters by using "auto". Regarding size of the text, axis-labels etc, use the standard arguments for generic plot function of base-R. I hope this answer helps you. Best wishes.